# What is the difference between '(a b c) and (list 'a 'b 'c)?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I am reading "On lisp" and encountered this code (I simplified it a bit).

```
CL-USER> (defun foo ()                                                          
           '(a b c))
FOO                                                                             
CL-USER> (foo)
(A B C)                                                                         
CL-USER> (nconc * '(D E))
(A B C D E)                                                                     
CL-USER> (foo)
(A B C D E) 
CL-USER> (defun foo ()                                                          
          (list 'a 'b 'c))
STYLE-WARNING: redefining FOO in DEFUN                                          
FOO                                                                             
CL-USER> (foo)
(A B C)                                                                         
CL-USER> (nconc * '(D E))
(A B C D E)                                                                     
CL-USER> (foo)
(A B C)
```

- What exactly does `*` mean? Is it the previous function call? Is it suitable to use in real world code?
- Why does `(nconc * '(D E))` change the return value of the first `foo` function?
- I always thought `(list 'a 'b 'c)` and `'(a b c)` are the same? What is the difference?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The call to LIST creates a new list each time it is evaluated.  The list literal might be placed in a read-only memory segment after compilation. A destructive update on the lists with NCONC is then problematic, possibly with undefined consequences (segmentation error, changing the literal for future references, or nothing at all).

Answer (score 8):

Variables `*`, `**` and `***` are specified by the language [standard](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v__stst_.htm) and they are quite useful when testing things. They are a feature of the REPL, and so are not, and not supposed to, be useful in a "real world code".